# SQL take 1 MAX from each group

Tags: sql, sql-server

We're on MS-SQL server 2016.
From a table similar to this (albeit simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE import_tbl 
    (
     id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     key_date datetime2, 
     key_number int,
     other_data char(3),
     units int
    );

INSERT INTO import_tbl
(key_number, key_date, other_data, units)
VALUES
(1000000, '2014-03-31 19:10:17.110', 'AAA', 300),
(1000000, '2014-03-31 19:10:17.110', 'BBB', 200),
(1000000, '2014-02-17 14:58:42.523', 'CCC', 100),
(1000000, '2014-02-17 13:43:40.570', 'DDD', 99),
(2000000, '2014-03-31 19:04:18.157', 'AAA', 100),
(2000000, '2014-03-31 19:04:18.157', 'AAA', 0),
(3000000, '2014-03-31 19:04:18.157', 'AAA', 500),
(3000000, '2014-03-31 19:04:18.157', 'BBB', 500),
(4000000, '2014-03-31 19:04:18.157', 'AAA', 700);
```

i am trying to take 1 record for each "key_number" ordered by:

1. latest key_date
2. higher number of units
3. in case of exact duplicates, take latest ID

so from example above, i expect these results:

```
1   2014-03-31 19:10:17.1100000 1000000 AAA 300
5   2014-03-31 19:04:18.1570000 2000000 AAA 100
8   2014-03-31 19:04:18.1570000 3000000 BBB 500
9   2014-03-31 19:04:18.1570000 4000000 AAA 700
```

I am trying to avoid using cursor or temp tables, is it possible?
so far i've got smth like:

```
SELECT i.* FROM import_tbl i
inner join 
 (select key_number, max(key_date) as key_date, max(units) as units 
    from import_tbl  
    group by key_number) as latest
 on latest.key_number = i.key_number and latest.key_date = i.key_date
```

but it's not quite right. 
Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f3e08/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost perfectly defined as an example for `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY key_number ORDER BY key_date DESC, units DESC, ID DESC) AS order_id
    FROM
        import_fbl)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    order_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same with TOP TIES, but personally I do not like it's syntax, my bet is row_number:

```
select *
from (
select *, 
row_number() over(partition by key_number order by key_date DESC,  units desc, id desc) rn
from import_tbl
) a
where rn = 1
```

Comment: think you're missing order by key_date

Comment: @tsar fixed query

Answer (score 2):

And here's the top/ties solution, which I prefer due to the lack of parentheses:

```
select top 1 * with ties
from import_tbl
order by row_number() over(partition by key_number order by key_date desc, units desc, id desc)
```

Comment: think you're missing order by key_date

Comment: Indeed! Changed the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `subquery` with *correlation* approach :

```
select i.*
from import_tbl i
where id = (select top 1 i1.id 
            from import_tbl i1
            where i.key_number = i1.key_number 
            order by i1.key_date desc, i1.units desc, i1.id desc
           );
```